# Sharing an Instance of a Cocoa FBA (Faceless Background Application or simply Agent)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shared-memory

**Objective**

I'm building an FBA (Faceless Background Application). Other applications (clients) register with the FBA using the NSDistributedNotificationCenter. When a client registers, i'd like to be able to invoke messages directly on the client object.

**First Issue:**

When the client posts a notification requesting registration, I originally wanted to set a userInfo key to the client.

> [NSValue valueWithPointer:self]; //
>   where self is the client application

However when the notification is posted, an error is generated saying the userInfo is not serializable.

**Issue 2:**
I created a work around by giving the userInfo a NSNumber instead.

> [NSNumber
>   numberWithUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)self];

The FBA now receives the appropriate pointer when it receives the notification. However when I try to access the object(the client), a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error is generated.

So, I guess my question is, how can I get access to another memory space? Do I have to create a shared memory space somehow? Is this possible? Am I stepping in the wrong direction with this design pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Well. After some more research I realize "Shared Memory" is quite a feat to tackle. I don't think it's worth investing that much time into it. Rather, i'll simply communicate via NSDistributedNotificationCenter. A bit tedious, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: You should definitely look into distributed objects as @skue pointed out as it will allow you to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sending notifications back and forth is definitely the simplest solution, if that works for you.

However, if you need more Cocoa supports distributed objects via `NSProxy` et al. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000102-SW1